# Whilst reading/retrieving data with orderByChild().equalTo()

Tags: java, android, firebase

I get an error when trying to add .on("value", function(snapshot)) or .once(...).then(...)
(Can't resolve method)

I have tried to follow this documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("random");

ref.on()
```

can't resolve method

Comment: can you add relevant code

Comment: you are using javascript.. why did you tag with android?

Comment: There is not much to show. I initialise my ref, then try to attach the method on() but it throws an error.

Comment: It seems that you're confusing Java and JavaScript. If you're creating an Android app, you're using Java (or Kotlin), and should read the documentation for **that** platform: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start. I also highly recommend that you take the [codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) as an easier way to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("random");
```

Is Java code and you trying the search for a solution in official documentation regarding Javascript. For Android you can use [DatabaseReference.CompletionListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener).

Comment: Oh mother. Thank you. Is there a more efficient way (such as this) in java?

Comment: No but here it's not about a more efficient way is the way it works.

Comment: Yes, evreything in Firebase is about listeners, when it comes to getting data.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read the official documentation regarding [getting started with Firebase on android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: Thank you I have been using firebase for a while now just made a mistake by clicking on the wrong documentation.